# Troubleshooting GET vs POST

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

There is a very basic confusion going in our project. We have a Servlet to which some parameters are passed in Query string and it constructs a JSON response for us. This works well. However if we pass the parameters in post, the response returned to us is different, the different being the order in which the results are returned.

So Logically - using queryparameter the result is 1,2,3,4,5
               Using post variables the result is 1,3,4,2,5

How do we troubleshoot this.

Comment: can't say until you share some piece of code.

Comment: You'd need to show (a) how you're submitting the data, and (b) how you're constructing the response. Also, if the order matters, consider enforcing order via a parameter naming convention.

Comment: Actually the data is submitted using a EXTJS widget. Something like this var proxy = new CQ.Ext.data.HttpProxy( {"url":  postProxyUrl,"method": "POST"} );
        var updatedSourceStore = new CQ.Ext.data.Store({
            proxy: proxy,
            reader: reader,
            baseParams:{ cattags:tagString1,headline:tempHeadlineData,typetags:tagString2}
        });
        updatedSourceStore.load();

Comment: GET and POST are two completely different things, though.  One is retrieving data given a set of query parameters; another is creating a new resource given certain data (either in a JSON post body or query parameters).  I would *hope* that the response you get back from successive POST is different each time, since it's not idempotent like GET is.

Comment: The only reason we are moving from GET to POST is because sometimes the querystring exceeds the size limit and thus returning no result. Actually to maintain the ordering of the items everytime we pass it in as a parameter value in querystring.( headline is the comma separated values)

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is, you can't guarantee any order. You'll need to name the request parameters according to the order you want and sort them on the server.

You might find that with a slightly different design, the requirement for processing them in some particular order goes away. Why does this requirement exist?

Follow the discussion on [retrieving request Parameters in order](http://www.coderanch.com/t/363967/Servlets/java/retrieving-request-Parameters-order) at JavaRanch.